# How to make an array with key-value pairs as integers, and loop through each key value pair to pass as arguments to my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

What I want to do is:

I have a function that animates a div's margin-left in percentage, with an associated distance counter (for another function):

```
function animateValue(amount, counter) {
    myDivToAnimate.animate({
        marginLeft: amount + '%'
    }, 1200, function () {
        slideCounterValue = counter;
    });
}
```

And I'm calling it as follows, decimal places are required for this:

```
animateValue(-100.5, -1)
```

What I want to do is make an array or an object (I'm not sure which), that has the arguments from above. So for example:

```
var myArray = [{-100.5: -1},{-200.8: -2},{-312.5: -3}...]
```

and then pass these to my animateValue() function.

I'm not sure how to either:

- Create the array with integers, which are negative and have decimals
- Pass these pairs from the array to my animateValue() arguments.

Finally, once I have sorted them, I need to randomize the array key-value pairs that are pulled, so that each time it animates to a different margin-left and associated counter value.

Probably it's a simple answer but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: how about using a plain array: `var offsets = [-100.5, -200.8, -312.5]` and using the indices: `var index = 2; animateValue(offsets[index], -1-index)`

Comment: don't use key-value pairs - it's a bad idea!  It's completely the wrong data model for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your array to object hash and use first parameter as object key, like this:

```
var myObject = {'-100.5': -1,'-200.8': -2,'-312.5': -3};
```

I've updated example with adding randomizing

```js
var myObject = {'-100.5': -1,'-200.8': -2,'-312.5': -3};
var keys = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a, b) {
  return Math.random() < Math.random() ? 1 : 0;
});

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, myObject[key]);
});
```

Comment: thank you, how do I randomize what's passed from the array to my function?

Comment: What do you mean randomize in this example?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by that is to pull random key-value pairs from the array. At the moment it pulls always the first key-value ('-100.5': -1), but I need it to be a different key-value each time. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated example with adding randomizing. Please check

Comment: I had an error on my end but this now works. One final thing, that I don't think I made clear in my question - it only needs to animate once. At the moment when I run it, it animates to the first key-value, then the 2nd, then the 3rd. I need it to only animate once. So it will animate to whatever random value is in the first key-value pair, and then stop. I've tried a few things here but I can't get it to stop looping through all the values!

Comment: Only once... So instead of using `keys.forEach` use only first randomized key `animate(keys[0], myObject[keys[0]])`. You mean this?

Comment: Using [`AssociativeArray.js`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JDMcKinstry/05fd4ba55184a065f33cf48c04f33d58/raw/a61b45b5f8f124a312312e22f51f6a9874ab9a53/AssociativeArray.js), Simply use your object as param such as `AssociativeArray({'-100.5': -1,'-200.8': -2,'-312.5': -3});` and get `instanceof Array` Object with proper length in return. Just for fun :P

Answer (score 1):

You can not have JSON key as negative integer. Please take it as a string and convert it according to you need.

```js
var myArray = [{"-100.5": -1},{"-200.8": -2},{"-312.5": -3}];

for(let i in myArray) {
  let tempObj = myArray[i];
  
  for(let key in tempObj) {
    //console.log(parseFloat(key) + "\t" + tempObj[key]);
    
    //call your function here
    animateValue(key, tempObj[key]);
  }
}

function animateValue(a, b) {
  console.log(a + "\t" + b);
}
```

Comment: How do I pass those values then to my function call? Is it something like:

animateValue(key, tempObj[key])?

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan I've updated the code for you and if you want to call the function in interval use `setTimeout` .

Comment: thank you!! It's indeed passing a key-value into the function. How do I then pass random values to the function? At the moment it's always the first key-value pair. Many thanks for this!

Comment: Using an object for the inner key / value pairs is a _bad idea_

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to keep values inside arrays, like below,

```
var myArray = [[-100.5, -1],[-200.8, -2],[-312.5, -3]];
```

then it is easy iterate over them and pass to a function.

Let's define a function, than accepts two numbers and uses them (in our case returns the value sums).

```
foo = function(a,b) { return a+b; }
```

then iterate over `myArray` and pass the inner array values as parameters to `foo` function.

```
> for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
... console.log(foo(myArray[i][0], myArray[i][1])); }
-101.5
-202.8
-315.5
```

or let's mock-up more realistic scenario.

```
> bar = function(a,b) {
... return "pseudo call to someFunction("+a+","+b+")";}
```

then,

```
> myArray.forEach(function(e){
... console.log(bar(e[0], e[1]));})
pseudo call to someFunction(-100.5,-1)
pseudo call to someFunction(-200.8,-2)
pseudo call to someFunction(-312.5,-3)
```